# Form inputs added with javascript do not show or hide when I click on radio or checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form with inputs like text, checkbox, selects and radio buttons.

Some of them are hidden by a `.js` file and will show when you do some action f.e. if you check on checkbox or choose radio button.

The problem is, if I click on the button `Add more` I add all of these inputs to order another product, but all of the inputs are already shown.

**EDIT:**

**php file** *(script copy only first inputs, then I have problem with hidding so I dont continue)*

```
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="into2.php" onsubmit="return kontrola();">
        <input type="hidden" id="refresh" value="no">
            <dl>
                <a href="index.php"><legend class="nadpis">OBJEDNÁVKA NÁRAMKU S MENOM ALEBO TEXTOM</legend></a>
            </dl>
            <dl><dt></dt><dd class="uvod-mob"><strong>Zvoľte počet náramkov a zistite cenu ;)</strong>
                    </dd>
                </dl>

        <div id="naramky">
            <hr height="2" color="#3db2e1">
            <dl>
                <legend class="nar">1. náramok</legend>
            </dl>
            <dl>
                <dt><label>Meno/názov:</label></dt>
                    <dd><input type="text" name="meno[] id="meno1" size="28" maxlength="128" placeholder="napíšte bez diakritiky" style='text-transform:uppercase' /></dd><dd class="info"><em>  "Namiesto srdiečka daj bodku"</em></dd>
            </dl>
            <dl>
                <dt><label>Farba:</label></dt>
                    <dd>
                        <select name="farba[]" id="farba1">
                            <option value="0">Zvoľte...</option>
                            <?php
                                $nfar =
                                "SELECT * FROM nfarba WHERE stav = 1 ORDER BY idnf  ";
                                $vysl2 = mysql_query($nfar);
                                while ($riadok = mysql_fetch_array($vysl2))
                                {
                                    if ($riadok["idnf"] == "1" )
                                    {
                                        echo "<option value=\"".$riadok["idnf"]."\">".$riadok["nfarba"]."</option>";
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        echo "<option value=\"".$riadok["idnf"]."\" >".$riadok["nfarba"]."</option>";
                                    }
                                }
                                    mysql_free_result($vysl2);
                            ?>
                        </select>
                    </dd>
        </dl>
        <dl>        
            <dt><label for="pismo1">Typ korálky:</label></dt>
                <dd>
                    <select name="pismo[]" id="pismo1">
                        <option value="0">Zvoľte...</option>
                        <?php
                            $ntyp =
                            "SELECT * FROM npismo WHERE stav = 1 ORDER BY idpis  ";
                            $vysl2 = mysql_query($ntyp);
                            while ($riadok = mysql_fetch_array($vysl2))
                            {
                                if ($riadok["idpis"] == "1" )
                                {
                                    echo "<option value=\"".$riadok["idpis"]."\">".$riadok["ntpis"]."</option>";
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    echo "<option value=\"".$riadok["idpis"]."\" >".$riadok["ntpis"]."</option>";
                                }
                            }
                                mysql_free_result($vysl2);
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </dd>
        </dl>
        <dl>
            <dt><label for="heart1">Srdiečko?</label></dt>
                <dd>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="heart1" name="heart[]" value=1 />
                </dd>
        </dl>
        <span id="srdce1" class="srdce1">
            <dl>
                <dt><label for="srdce_farba1">Farba:</label></dt>
                    <dd>
                        <select name="srdce_farba[]" id="srdce_farba1">
                            <option value="0">Zvoľte...</option>
                                    <?php
                                $sfar =
                                "SELECT * FROM nfarbas WHERE stav = 1 ORDER BY idfs  ";
                                $vysl2 = mysql_query($sfar);
                                while ($riadok = mysql_fetch_array($vysl2))
                                {
                                    if ($riadok["idfs"] == "1" )
                                    {
                                        echo "<option value=\"".$riadok["idfs"]."\">".$riadok["nfarbas"]."</option>";
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        echo "<option value=\"".$riadok["idfs"]."\" >".$riadok["nfarbas"]."</option>";
                                    }
                                }
                                    mysql_free_result($vysl2);
                            ?>
                        </select>
                    </dd>
            </dl>
            <dl>
                <dt><label for="srdce_place1">Umiestnenie:</label></dt>
                    <dd>
                        <select name="srdce_place[]" id="srdce_place1">
                            <option value="0">Zvoľte...</option>
                                    <?php
                                $splac =
                                "SELECT * FROM nsrplace  ORDER BY idsrplace  ";
                                $vysl2 = mysql_query($splac);
                                while ($riadok = mysql_fetch_array($vysl2))
                                {
                                    if ($riadok["idsrplace"] == "1" )
                                    {
                                        echo "<option value=\"".$riadok["idsrplace"]."\">".$riadok["srplace"]."</option>";
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        echo "<option value=\"".$riadok["idsrplace"]."\" >".$riadok["srplace"]."</option>";
                                    }
                                }
                                    mysql_free_result($vysl2);
                            ?>
                        </select>
                    </dd>
            </dl>
        </span>
        <dl>
            <dt><label for="radio1">Viete obvod?</label></dt>
                <dd class="label">
                    <input type="radio" name="radio[0]" id="radio1_y" value="1" /><label class="radio">Áno</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="radio[0]" id="radio1_n" value="0" /><label class="radio">Nie</label>
                </dd>
        </dl>
        <span id="rozmer1" class="rozmer1">
            <dl>
            <dt><label for="obvod1">Obvod ruky:</label></dt>
                <dd><input type="text" name="obvod[]" id="obvod1" maxlength="50" placeholder="obvod zápästia v cm" /></dd>
            </dl>
        </span>
            <dl>
            <span id="pohl1" class="pohl1">
                <dt><label for="genre1">Bude ho nosiť:</label></dt>
                    <dd>
                        <select name="genre[]" id="genre1">
                            <option value=0>Zvoľte ...</option>
                            <option value=1>chlapec</option>
                            <option value=2>dievča</option>
                        </select>
        </span>
        <span id="age1" class="age1">
                        <label for="age1">  Vek?:</label>       
                        <input type="text" class="age" name="age[]" id="age1" size="2" />
        </span>        
                    </dd>
            </dl>
        <dl>
            <dt><label for="poznamka1">Poznámka:</label></dt>
                <dd>
                    <input type="text" class="pozn" name="poznamka[]" id="poznamka1" size="28" maxlength="255" placeholder="napríklad: druhá farba" />
                </dd>
        </dl>
</div>
        <dl>
            <p align="center">
                <input type="button" id="addNew" value="Pridať ďalší" />
            </p>
        </dl>

    <script language="javascript"  type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        var wrapper = $("#naramky");
                        var add_button = $("#addNew");
                        var x = 1;
                        var r = 1;
                        $(add_button).click(function(e) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            $(wrapper).append('<br><br><br><br><dl><legend class="nar">' + x++ + '. náramok</legend></dl>');
                            $(wrapper).append('<dl><dt><label>Meno/názov:</label></dt><dd><input type="text" name="meno[] id="meno1" size="28" maxlength="128" placeholder="napíšte bez diakritiky" style="text-transform:uppercase"/></dd><dd class="info"><em>  "Namiesto srdiečka daj bodku"</em></dd></dl>');
                            $(wrapper).append('<dl><dt><label>Farba:</label></dt><dd><select name="farba[]" id="farba1"><option value="0">Zvoľte...</option><?php $nfar =   "SELECT * FROM nfarba WHERE stav = 1 ORDER BY idnf  "; $vysl2 = mysql_query($nfar); while ($riadok = mysql_fetch_array($vysl2)){ if ($riadok["idnf"] == "1" ){ echo "<option value=\"".$riadok["idnf"]."\">".$riadok["nfarba"]."</option>"; } else{ echo "<option value=\"".$riadok["idnf"]."\" >".$riadok["nfarba"]."</option>"; } } ?></select></dd></dl>');
                            $(wrapper).append('<dl><dt><label for="pismo1">Typ korálky:</label></dt><dd><select name="pismo[]" id="pismo1"><option value="0">Zvoľte...</option><?php
                                $ntyp =
                                "SELECT * FROM npismo WHERE stav = 1 ORDER BY idpis  ";
                                $vysl2 = mysql_query($ntyp);
                                while ($riadok = mysql_fetch_array($vysl2))
                                {
                                    if ($riadok["idpis"] == "1" )
                                    {
                                        echo "<option value=\"".$riadok["idpis"]."\">".$riadok["ntpis"]."</option>";
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        echo "<option value=\"".$riadok["idpis"]."\" >".$riadok["ntpis"]."</option>";
                                    }
                                }
                                    mysql_free_result($vysl2);
                            ?></select> </dd></dl>');
                            $(wrapper).append('<dl><dt><label for="heart' + r++ + '">Srdiečko?</label></dt><dd><input type="checkbox" id="heart' + r + '" name="heart[]" value=1 /></dd></dl>');
                            $(wrapper).append('<div id="srdce' + r + '" class="srdce' + r + '"><dl><dt><label for="srdce_farba1">Farba:</label></dt><dd><select name="srdce_farba[]" id="srdce_farba1"><option value="0">Zvoľte...</option><?php
                                    $sfar =
                                    "SELECT * FROM nfarbas WHERE stav = 1 ORDER BY idfs  ";
                                    $vysl2 = mysql_query($sfar);
                                    while ($riadok = mysql_fetch_array($vysl2))
                                    {
                                        if ($riadok["idfs"] == "1" )
                                        {
                                            echo "<option value=\"".$riadok["idfs"]."\">".$riadok["nfarbas"]."</option>";
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            echo "<option value=\"".$riadok["idfs"]."\" >".$riadok["nfarbas"]."</option>";
                                        }
                                    }
                                        mysql_free_result($vysl2);
                                ?></select></dd></dl></div>');

    });
    });
            </script>
```

**js file**

```
    $(document).ready(function()
  {
      $('#srdce1').hide();
      $('#heart1').change(function()
        {
          if(this.checked)
            $('#srdce1').fadeIn('slow');
          else
            $('#srdce1').fadeOut('slow');
        });
  });

    $(document).ready(function(){
 $('#rozmer1').hide();
 $('#pohl1').hide();

        $('input[type="radio"][name="radio[0]"]').click(function(){
            if($(this).attr("value")=="1"){
                $('#rozmer1').fadeIn('slow');
                 $('#pohl1').hide();
                 $('#age1').hide();
                 function setSelectValue (id, val) {
    document.getElementById(id).value = val;
}
setSelectValue('genre1', 0);
            }
            if($(this).attr("value")=="0"){
                 $('#rozmer1').hide();
                $('#pohl1').fadeIn('slow');
                $('#age1').hide();
                function setSelectValue (id, val) {
    document.getElementById(id).value = val;
}
setSelectValue('genre1', 0);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: yes, in few minutes

Comment: Since you are appending it to the dom, you can't set the visibility through `jQuery`, what you can do is, while appending your elements use inline css like `"style=display:none"` to have them hidden while it is getting dynmically appended.

Comment: ok, i made them hidden...but, when I check checkbox "heart1" they (srdce1) dont be visible...

Comment: Use `$('#srdce1').show()` inside your `$('#heart1').change(function()...` function.

Comment: No, my js code si good...when I check checkbox then js do that show div id #srdce1 which contains two inputs...these inputs I want to have hidden when checkbox is false.. problem is...when I click add for add new same inputs...and then try chceck second (added by script) checkbox and I wait for show div #srdce2 nothing happen...this is problem...

Comment: wall of code not good. isolate problem

Comment: spelling, grammer and removal of superfluous intro, outro statements.